# How to hide/not display SSL certificates in Github repos

Tags: security, github, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to find the best way/command/tactic to hide or not display SSL certificates in a Github repo. I can't seem to find any reference links on this doing a google search.

Any tips or tricks?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to do that, if you do not want it to show up in github, include the file name in `.gitignore` file.